# Missing CAssetManager.php

Tags: yii

This happens every day to my site
Like CAssetManager.php is being deleted. And then I have to upload framework all over again, or just add that file. CAssetManager.php is somehow being deleted by itself.

I'm sure it's not my script, since I've used gii code generator and modify code to alter database

```
Warning: include() [function.include]: Unable to access /home/dtrbovic/yii/web/CAssetManager.php in /home/dtrbovic/yii/YiiBase.php on line 403

Warning: include(/home/dtrbovic/yii/web/CAssetManager.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dtrbovic/yii/YiiBase.php on line 403

Warning: include() [function.include]: Unable to access /home/dtrbovic/yii/web/CAssetManager.php in /home/dtrbovic/yii/YiiBase.php on line 403

Warning: include(/home/dtrbovic/yii/web/CAssetManager.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dtrbovic/yii/YiiBase.php on line 403

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/dtrbovic/yii/web/CAssetManager.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/modules/message/components:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/modules/message/models:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/modules/user/components:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/modules/user/models:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/modules/user/components:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/modules/user/models:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/components:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/models:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/dtrbovic/yii/YiiBase.php on line 403

Warning: include() [function.include]: Unable to access /home/dtrbovic/yii/web/CAssetManager.php in /home/dtrbovic/yii/YiiBase.php on line 403

Warning: include(/home/dtrbovic/yii/web/CAssetManager.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dtrbovic/yii/YiiBase.php on line 403

Warning: include() [function.include]: Unable to access /home/dtrbovic/yii/web/CAssetManager.php in /home/dtrbovic/yii/YiiBase.php on line 403

Warning: include(/home/dtrbovic/yii/web/CAssetManager.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dtrbovic/yii/YiiBase.php on line 403

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/dtrbovic/yii/web/CAssetManager.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/modules/message/components:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/modules/message/models:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/modules/user/components:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/modules/user/models:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/modules/user/components:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/modules/user/models:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/components:/home/dtrbovic/public_html/protected/models:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/dtrbovic/yii/YiiBase.php on line 403

Fatal error: Class 'CAssetManager' not found in /home/dtrbovic/yii/YiiBase.php on line 217
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible. I think there is a specific virus on your server. You make some script that checks when it file deleting, in what time. Also you may set chmod for only reading and executing from root

Comment: Agree. It is not something Yii does so must third-party code.

Comment: you were right, it was because of

Regular expression match = [symlink\s*\(]: